if name in Column A is lower in Column B, turn cell color
For example...
Column A

John
Pete
Sam

Column B

Sam
Pete
John

I'd like the "Sam" Cell in Column B to turn a color
Google'd a TON of conditional formatting tutorials, but can't find anything similar.
Any help would be incredibly appreciated!!!

Is there going to be a scenario where there could be multiple Sam in Column_A (lets say one upper & one lower) OR its always unique?!

You should use "custom" rules for Conditional format. Conditional formats accepts that returns boolean and only highlights TRUE cell. However, the target cell is relative from the top-left cell of selection unless you "pin" its position by $ sign as usual.
I'm assuming following:

Column A and B has exact same names
and no duplicates
You are trying to highlight column B's cell where ROW(column A's cell having same value) >= ROW(column B's cell)

What about put B1:B3 for the range and set =MATCH(B1, $A$1:$A$3, 0)>ROW() for condition? It yields:


Addition:

Would it be possible to adjust the formula so a cell also turns green if a totally new name showed up in Column B?

Yes. You would use OR function to make disjunction. MATCH returns #N/A if range does not have corresponding value, so one solution would be =IFNA(MATCH(B1, $A$1:$A$3, 0), 9999999)>ROW().
It yields:

(Note: Column C demonstrates how MATCH returns)

Thank you so much! Yes! You absolutely nailed it. Thank you for the detailed explanation as well, learned something new!

Would it be possible to adjust the formula so a cell also turns green if a totally new name showed up in Column B?

@sn8ks Yes, I've updated this answer.


Select the range in Column B: Click on the header of Column B to highlight the entire column.
Open Conditional Formatting:
Go to the menu and select Format.
Choose Conditional formatting.
3.Set up the Custom Formula:
In the Conditional format rules pane on the right, make sure the range applies to the cells in Column B.
If you want to apply it only to a specific range, adjust the range accordingly.
Under Format cells if, choose Custom formula is.
4.Enter the Custom Formula:
=MATCH(B1, A:A, 0) > ROW(B1) - ROW($B$1) + 1


Thank you!! Really appreciate the descriptive response. Would it be possible to ALSO change a cell to green if a totally new name showed up in Column B within that formula?

Yes
1.Select the range in Column B: Click on the header of Column B to highlight the entire column or select the specific range you want to apply the rule to.
2.Open Conditional Formatting:
Go to the menu and select Format.
Choose Conditional formatting.
3.Set up the first Custom Formula for matching names:
In the Conditional format rules pane on the right, ensure the range applies to the cells in Column B.
Under Format cells if, choose Custom formula is.
Enter the following formula:
=MATCH(B1, A:A, 0) > ROW(B1) - ROW($B$1) + 1
Choose your formatting style (e.g., red background) for names that appear earlier in Column A.
Click on Done

Sorry, I don't think I'm understanding that edit. Isn't that the same formula? Looking for the cells to turn green if: name is higher in column B, AND if a totally new name appears in column B.
